# Unable to update web settings for Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I updated my function app from Function runtime v3, .NET core 3.1 to Function runtime v4 and .NET 6. I am encountering the following error every time I publish it. Everything still works though. If I deploy the old version of the function app. I don't see this error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is your code working locally after upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

Following steps Worked for me:

Make sure you are using `Function Runtime` version in the Azure is `4`as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Install latest version of `Azure Function Core tools`. you can download it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows,in-process,node-v4,python-v2,http-trigger,container-apps&pivots=programming-language-csharp#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools).

I have created a sample HTTP trigger.

Make sure correct version of `.NET` And `Function Runtime` is mentioned in the `.csproj` file:

**`.csprojfile`:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**#`OUTPUT`:**

**local:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**#Azure**
[image]

[image]

**Get the function `url`:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. I have the same error.